# App get suspended from background state even if app playing a music

Tags: ios, swift, audio-player, suspend, background-music

I have a music player application. Where user can listen music even the app is not in foreground as desire. Everything's work fine.

Now the problem is when user left the device idle music playing smoothly. But after two or three songs it's stop working. As far I noticed when a song ended it's trying to change the track. For that app needs to execute some business logic but it is not happening as system suspended the app. I tried the following.

Capabilities:

[image]

Audio session:

```
do {
      try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
      try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
} catch {
      print("Failed to register")
}
```

Still it's not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: check memory usage .

Comment: Its consuming maximum 30-35 mb.

Comment: @datha what's next?

Comment: i thought app suspend happened due to memory consumption.which player are you using?

Comment: @datha it's AVPlayer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to execute your business logic and **start playing next track** as quick as possible, once you finish a track in the background.

The iOS suspend your app if it's not playing audio in the background for about 3~4 seconds. If your business logic exceed this time limit,  try `UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask` before execute your logic.